# Excel VBA types converting error

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I'm collecting data from Excel files (hundreds or thousands of files) to one resulting Excel table using SQL query.

> Problem is:

somehow all numbers in Excel files are stored in Date format (ADO Fields(i).Type = 7) and while converting them back to numeric format ex. `myVar = cDbl(recordset.Fields(8).Value)` I receive result bigger then origin by 1.

This error occures for number smaller then 60 (earlier then 01.03.1900 respectivly).

Should be common problem but I couldn't find any straight idea how to fix it.

Comment: This doesn't seem right. There is no `Dim` for Counter as far as I can see before `Counter = Counter + 1`. So, in the first run it is 0 and therefore the first `ReDim` will go from 1 to 0 and then from 1 to 1. Could it be that you are stirring up your array? By default VBA uses the `Option Base 0`. So, I'd change your line to `ReDim Preserve o_Summ(0 To Counter)` or set Counter to 1 (before the loop), `Dim` it as `Long`, and use `ReDim Preserve o_Summ(Counter)` (stating the elements only and not where to start or where to end).

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense? The fso.GetFolder(Path) loop is not adding anything to your inner rs.eof loop.

Answer (score 0):

Just curious with this issue and found the problem.  There is a bug in lotus 1-2-3 as it assumes 1900 is a leap year and Excel replicate the bug deliberately https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/214326.

On the excel I change the cell format to date time:

- 59 as 28 Feb 1900
- 60 as 29 Feb 1900

However in ADO field's value, both are displayed as 28 Feb 1900 and when converted to double both values are 60.

The only way I can think of to solve this issue is to open your data worksheet, change the cell format to general.

EDIT: Test Data
[image]